# Postgres DB Schema - multiple columns vs one json column

Tags: postgresql, database-design, bigdata, schema

I have a db that contains username with 3 different phone numbers and 3 different ids. also we will have 3 different type of notes for each username.

I am using postgres and data are planned to increase to millions of rows. querying and inserting new data process are really important to be fastest way.

which schema would be better for that:

```
username | no1(string) | no2(string) | no3(string) | id1(string) | id2(string) | | id3(string) | note1(string) | note2(string) | note3(string)
```

OR

```
username | no(JSON) | id(JSON) | note(JSON)
```

Comment: Use the version without JSON. If you are unsure, benchmark your queries with a reasonable amount of test data.

Comment: Neither.  I'd start with the first schema and normalize it so each phone number / note is in its own row.

Comment: While both comments above are good suggestions, I will recommend you put some effort into learning database normalization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization is a good start.